# side bar hide using javascript or angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using below jquery script for my project. but i need to do this using javascript or angular js. not from jquery. how i do it.
my function

```
    $('.menu-item').click(function () {
        if ($(window).width() < 767) {
            $("body").removeClass("sidebar-open");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This how you do it in javascript, basicaly I converted your jQuery code to vanilla  javascript:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector(".menu-item")

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (window.screen.width < 767) {
    document.body.classList.remove("sidebar-open")
  }
})
```

Comment: can i use this without call function ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use pure vanilla JS to replace jquery. Based on your previous code it might be:

```
var button = document.querySelector('.menu-item');
button.addEventListener("click", function(){
if (window.width < 767) {
  document.body.classList.remove("sidebar-open");
}});
```

Comment: can i use this without call function ?

Comment: I don't think so. However, why don't you use css to solve this?

Comment: how i do click event using css? do u know any alternatives

Comment: I mean you can use css to make for example your sidebar hidden when the size of the window resized to below 767 using css media queries. Anyway, are you really need triggering a button click to do this?